# Updating an html5 progress bar in a loop

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar

In the following code the value of the html5 `<progress>` tag is updated every cicle. 
I can also see its value dynamically changing using the Chrome's console. 
But why the rendering is updated only at the end of the cycle?

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf8"></meta>
<title></title>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

  <button>click</button>
  <progress  min="0" max="10000" value="0"></progress>

  <script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        for(var i=0; i<8000; i++)
            $("progress").val(i)
    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `animate` method to make the progress of the bar more visible to the user, something like this :

```
$("button").click(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<800; i++)
        $("progress").animate({ value: "+=10" }, 1);
})
```

You can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/qZJN3/

Comment: This solution is valid with jquery 1.9.1 but not with the jquery-latest of June 17, 2013

Answer (score 8):

This will be because you are locking the UI. This code runs in the same thread as the code to update the UI, so even though you update the value of the progress bar, there is no time for the processor to update the UI.

The simplest way to fix this is to run your loop in a timeout:

```
    $("button").click(function(){
        var count = 0;

        var timeout = setTimeout(doLoop, 0);

        function doLoop() {
            $("progress").val(count);
            count++;
            if(count < 8000) {
                var timeout = setTimeout(doLoop, 0);
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(timeout)
            }
        }
    });
```

This will now run your code asynchronously. It means that there is time for the UI thread to update the UI inbetween processing your loop.

For a more advanced way for doing this in modern browsers, I recommend you also look at web workers, but this is the best cross browser way still.

Comment: Your answer is complete and teaches a lot. I will mark @andri's answer as correct as it is straightforward, but surely your comment will be useful in other circumstancies. Thanks!

Comment: additionally, web workers do not work locally.